# I want to install the Stackify Prefix on my workstation, but how do I run it?

Tags: .net, stackify

The Stackify Prefix tool looks very useful for my .Net applications.
So I visit the site and download it.
See

```
http://www.prefix.io/?utm_source=Twitter&utm_medium=PromotedTweet&utm_campaign=PrefixOne
```

When I try to run it for the first time it askes me how I want to open it and gives my a very odd filename for the suffix.
I do not know is my answer. How do you open it?

Comment: I noticed earlier today that the Prefix download doesn't have an extension, rename it to an EXE.

Comment: I just downloaded it from the download button on the link here.  had the exe extension as expected for me.

Comment: @EKW - that is the correct answer, thanks. Please make this the answer and I will award you with the coveted tick.

Comment: @arame3333 It would be better to delete the question; this isn't a useful question for SO, since it is a misconfiguration on the stackify servers. But thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you install Prefix it should be running on the following url http://localhost:2012. It will show you the dialog. 
But to get it start tracing you need to run something of your IIS server[image]

You can then disable the profiler if you need.